# Is there a way to access the contents of a NetCDF stored in a URL on Google Cloud Storage without downloading the file?

Tags: python-requests, google-cloud-storage, netcdf, gsutil

This is my first time asking a question so please let me know if I need to add any further information.

I am trying to access the object data in a public bucket on Google Cloud Storage but the data are in NetCDF format. I want to pull the data and avoid having the download the data locally. Similar to how the `netCDF4` library can access data from URL's that use DAP protocol. I need to be able access the data in multiple links at the same time so I can automate the URL links for a larger project I am working on.

[Here is a link to one of the objects I will be using](https://console.cloud.google.com/storage/browser/_details/national-water-model/nwm.20200501/short_range/nwm.t00z.short_range.channel_rt.f001.conus.nc)

If you click on the Link URL then the file is downloaded to NetCDF.

I know you can use gsutil or an HTTP client like requests to get the link but is there a a way to access the data stored in the NetCDF file after that?

edits:

Here is what my code looks like using the downloaded NetCDF file

input:

```py
import netCDF4 as nc
from netCDF4 import *

link = nc.Dataset('nwm.20200501_short_range_nwm.t00z.short_range.channel_rt.f001.conus.nc')
link
```

output:

```py
<class 'netCDF4._netCDF4.Dataset'>
root group (NETCDF4 data model, file format HDF5):
    featureType: timeSeries
    proj4: +proj=lcc +units=m +a=6370000.0 +b=6370000.0 +lat_1=30.0 +lat_2=60.0 +lat_0=40.0 +lon_0=-97.0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +k_0=1.0 +nadgrids=@
    model_initialization_time: 2020-05-01_00:00:00
    station_dimension: feature_id
    model_output_valid_time: 2020-05-01_01:00:00
    model_total_valid_times: 18
    stream_order_output: 1
    cdm_datatype: Station
    Conventions: CF-1.6
    code_version: v5.1.0-beta2
    NWM_version_number: v2.0
    model_output_type: channel_rt
    model_configuration: short_range
    dev_OVRTSWCRT: 1
    dev_NOAH_TIMESTEP: 3600
    dev_channel_only: 0
    dev_channelBucket_only: 0
    dev: dev_ prefix indicates development/internal meta data
    dimensions(sizes): feature_id(2729077), time(1), reference_time(1)
    variables(dimensions): int32 time(time), int32 reference_time(reference_time), |S1 crs(), int32 feature_id(feature_id), int32 streamflow(feature_id), int32 nudge(feature_id), int32 velocity(feature_id), int32 qSfcLatRunoff(feature_id), int32 qBucket(feature_id), int32 qBtmVertRunoff(feature_id)
    groups:
```

I'm currently using the  `requests` API but I'm wondering if I can use this method to access the same data presented above?

```py
import requests as req

r = req.get('https://storage.cloud.google.com/national-water-model/nwm.20200501/short_range/nwm.t00z.short_range.channel_rt.f001.conus.nc')
```

Answer (score 4):

So there are a couple of options. If you don't need to sign in, then newer versions of the netCDF-C library can read data over HTTP directly using byte-range requests--provided this option was enabled when the library was compiled. The latest versions available on conda-forge (a packaging channel for the conda/Anaconda Python ecosystem) now have this enabled. With this enabled, you can directly open the url with `#mode=bytes` appended:

```
from netCDF4 import Dataset

url = ('https://storage.cloud.google.com/national-water-model/nwm.20200501/'
       'short_range/nwm.t00z.short_range.channel_rt.f001.conus.nc#mode=bytes')
link = Dataset(url)
```

Now I tried that with your URL above and it fails with "Unknown file format" because it looks like that Google Cloud URL needs authentication. If you can figure out some way to pass that authentication to libcurl using a config file or environment variables, then the code above might work. The other option is to download the file contents into an in-memory buffer and then open that:

```
import requests
from netCDF4 import Dataset

url = ('https://storage.cloud.google.com/national-water-model/nwm.20200501/'
       'short_range/nwm.t00z.short_range.channel_rt.f001.conus.nc#mode=bytes')
data = requests.get(url).content
link = Dataset('anynamehere', memory=data)
```

Comment: Wouldn't the second alternative download the entire file no matter what?

Comment: That's correct. All you're saving with that is any need to manually/programmatically download the file and manage it on disk.

Answer (score -1):

The phrasing in your question is a bit confusing. If you're accessing the contents of a file, you're downloading it ("downloading" means transferring the object's bytes over the network from GCS to your host machine, regardless of whether you're saving them to a file on disk, printing them to your terminal, etc.).

> I want to pull the data and avoid having the download the data locally

What do you mean by "pull the data"? If you mean access the contents, that *is* downloading it. If you want to see the object's metadata, you can either make an HTTP `GET` call to get the appropriate metadata or, depending on what information you need, use something like `curl` to make a `HEAD` request against the object's URL.

> since I will be automating the URL links

What do you mean by "automating the URL links"? Do you mean you'll be generating URLs for users to download the objects themselves? If so, you can just plug the bucket and object name into GCS's storage.googleapis.com endpoint, which is intended for use with serving public objects. The format is [explained in the web docs](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/request-endpoints#access_to_public_objects), but it generally follows one of these forms:

```
https://<BUCKET>.storage.googleapis.com/<OBJECT>
https://storage.googleapis.com/<BUCKET>/<OBJECT>
```

Comment: Thank you for asking for clarification @mhouglum. I will edit my post to make more sense. In short, using the netcdf4 and similar API you can access the contents of the file without downloading the file if the URL uses DAP protocol, however the URL on GCS is HTTP. I want to know if there is a way to access the contents in the file without having to download the file similar to what can be done with the netCDF4 API, ill include examples in my edit.

Comment: And by automating the link I mean I will need to access a number of the objects in the bucket at the same time. Since the different links vary by number increments I can create a program to change the link through a loop in order to get the links I need.

Comment: Ah, I'd not heard of the DAP protocol before. Neat. Looking at docs.opendap.org, it appears that the server you're fetching data from needs to support DAP; data stored in GCS is only served via its APIs over HTTP, not DAP.  To view the contents of a file, you have to download it (either completely, or partially using the `Range` HTTP header), regardless of whether you store it to disk or just read it into memory.  If you want metadata like in your example , it would need to be stored as custom metadata on the desired object: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/metadata#custom-metadata